# Kafka Consumer Unable To Resolve Listener Method Intermittently

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have been facing the exception below on the Kafka consumer side. Surprisingly, this issue is **not consistent** and an older version of the code (with the exact same configuration but some new unrelated features) works as expected. Could anyone help in determining what could be causing this?

```
[ERROR][938f3c68-f481-4224-b2c6-43af5fb27ada-0-C-1][org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer] - Error handler threw an exception
org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Seek to current after exception; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method could not be invoked with the incoming message
Endpoint handler details:
Method [public void com.mycompany.listener.KafkaBatchListener.onMessage(java.lang.Object,org.springframework.kafka.support.Acknowledgment)]
Bean [com.mycompany.listener.KafkaBatchListener@7a59780b]; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.MethodArgumentResolutionException: Could not resolve method parameter at index 0 in public void com.mycompany.listener.KafkaBatchListener.onMessage(java.util.List<org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord<K, V>>,org.springframework.kafka.support.Acknowledgment): Could not resolve parameter [0] in public void com.mycompany.listener.KafkaBatchListener.onMessage(java.util.List<org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord<K, V>>,org.springframework.kafka.support.Acknowledgment): No suitable resolver, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=[[B@21bc784f, MyPOJO(), [B@33bb5851], headers={kafka_offset=[4046, 4047, 4048], kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@4871203f, kafka_timestampType=[CREATE_TIME, CREATE_TIME, CREATE_TIME], kafka_receivedPartitionId=[0, 0, 0], kafka_receivedMessageKey=[[B@295620f1, MyPOJOKey(id=0), [B@5d3d6361], kafka_batchConvertedHeaders=[{myFirstHeader=[B@1f011689, myUUIDHeader=[B@7691bce8, myMetadataHeader=[B@6e585b63, myRequestIdHeader=[B@58c81ba2, myMetricsHeader=[B@4f6aeb6c, myTargetHeader=[B@34677895}, {myUUIDHeader=[B@1848ae39, myMetadataHeader=[B@c5b399, myRequestIdHeader=[B@186c1966, myMetricsHeader=[B@1740692e, myTargetHeader=[B@4a242499}, {myUUIDHeader=[B@67d01f3f, myMetadataHeader=[B@1f0f9d8a, myRequestIdHeader=[B@b928e5c, isLastMessage=[B@6079735b, myMetricsHeader=[B@7b7b18c, myTargetHeader=[B@64378f3d}], kafka_receivedTopic=[my_topic, my_topic, my_topic], kafka_receivedTimestamp=[1623420136620, 1623420137255, 1623420137576], kafka_acknowledgment=Acknowledgment for org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords@7bc81d89, kafka_groupId=dev-consumer-grp}]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler.handle(SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler.java:77) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.RecoveringBatchErrorHandler.handle(RecoveringBatchErrorHandler.java:124) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.ContainerAwareBatchErrorHandler.handle(ContainerAwareBatchErrorHandler.java:56) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeBatchErrorHandler(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2010) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeBatchListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1854) [spring-kafka-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeBatchListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1720) [spring-kafka-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1699) [spring-kafka-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeIfHaveRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1272) [spring-kafka-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1264) [spring-kafka-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1161) [spring-kafka-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
Caused by: org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method could not be invoked with the incoming message
Endpoint handler details:
Method [public void com.mycompany.listener.KafkaBatchListener.onMessage(java.lang.Object,org.springframework.kafka.support.Acknowledgment)]
Bean [com.mycompany.listener.KafkaBatchListener@7a59780b]; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.MethodArgumentResolutionException: Could not resolve method parameter at index 0 in public void com.mycompany.listener.KafkaBatchListener.onMessage(java.util.List<org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord<K, V>>,org.springframework.kafka.support.Acknowledgment): Could not resolve parameter [0] in public void com.mycompany.listener.KafkaBatchListener.onMessage(java.util.List<org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord<K, V>>,org.springframework.kafka.support.Acknowledgment): No suitable resolver, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=[[B@21bc784f, MyPOJO(), [B@33bb5851], headers={kafka_offset=[4046, 4047, 4048], kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@4871203f, kafka_timestampType=[CREATE_TIME, CREATE_TIME, CREATE_TIME], kafka_receivedPartitionId=[0, 0, 0], kafka_receivedMessageKey=[[B@295620f1, MyPOJOKey(id=0), [B@5d3d6361], kafka_batchConvertedHeaders=[{myFirstHeader=[B@1f011689, myUUIDHeader=[B@7691bce8, myMetadataHeader=[B@6e585b63, myRequestIdHeader=[B@58c81ba2, myMetricsHeader=[B@4f6aeb6c, myTargetHeader=[B@34677895}, {myUUIDHeader=[B@1848ae39, myMetadataHeader=[B@c5b399, myRequestIdHeader=[B@186c1966, myMetricsHeader=[B@1740692e, myTargetHeader=[B@4a242499}, {myUUIDHeader=[B@67d01f3f, myMetadataHeader=[B@1f0f9d8a, myRequestIdHeader=[B@b928e5c, isLastMessage=[B@6079735b, myMetricsHeader=[B@7b7b18c, myTargetHeader=[B@64378f3d}], kafka_receivedTopic=[my_topic, my_topic, my_topic], kafka_receivedTimestamp=[1623420136620, 1623420137255, 1623420137576], kafka_acknowledgment=Acknowledgment for org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords@7bc81d89, kafka_groupId=dev-consumer-grp}]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.decorateException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2367) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeBatchOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2003) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeBatchOnMessageWithRecordsOrList(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1973) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeBatchOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1925) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeBatchListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1837) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.MethodArgumentResolutionException: Could not resolve method parameter at index 0 in public void com.mycompany.listener.KafkaBatchListener.onMessage(java.util.List<org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord<K, V>>,org.springframework.kafka.support.Acknowledgment): Could not resolve parameter [0] in public void com.mycompany.listener.KafkaBatchListener.onMessage(java.util.List<org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord<K, V>>,org.springframework.kafka.support.Acknowledgment): No suitable resolver
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:145) ~[spring-messaging-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:116) ~[spring-messaging-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:56) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:339) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.BatchMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invoke(BatchMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:180) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.BatchMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(BatchMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:172) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.BatchMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(BatchMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:61) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeBatchOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1983) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeBatchOnMessageWithRecordsOrList(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1973) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeBatchOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1925) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeBatchListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1837) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    ... 8 more
```

My app uses the following:

1. A custom listener class `com.mycompany.listener.KafkaBatchListener<K, V>` which *implements* `org.springframework.kafka.listener.BatchAcknowledgingMessageListener<K, V>` and *overrides* `onMessage(List<ConsumerRecord<K, V>> consumerRecords, Acknowledgment acknowledgment)` with a custom marker annotation `@MyKafkaListener`
2. A custom container factory which *extends* `org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<K, V>` and configures `setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory)`, `setBatchErrorHandler(errorHandler)`, `setBatchListener(true)` and `ContainerProperties.setOnlyLogRecordMetadata(true)`.
3. A SpringBoot `@Configuration` class which *implements* `org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListenerConfigurer` and is responsible for configuring `org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<K, V>`, `org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<K, V>` and `org.springframework.kafka.config.MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint<String, String>` (used by `@MyKafkaListener`)
4. Spring Kafka 2.7.1

**Additional query:**
Even though `ContainerProperties.setOnlyLogRecordMetadata(true)` is set, the exception stacktrace still contains the full *payload* which I have omitted. Any idea why?

Thanks in advance!

---

**UPDATE:**

1. KafkaBatchListener

```
package com.mycompany.listener;

import java.util.List;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.springframework.kafka.listener.BatchAcknowledgingMessageListener;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.Acknowledgment;

public class KafkaBatchListener<K, V> implements BatchAcknowledgingMessageListener<K, V> {

    @Override
    @com.mycompany.listener.KafkaListener
    public void onMessage(final List<ConsumerRecord<K, V>> consumerRecords, final Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {

        // process batch using MyService<K, V>.process(consumerRecords)
        acknowledgment.acknowledge();
    }
}
```

2. Custom Annotation

```
package com.mycompany.listener;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(METHOD)
public @interface KafkaListener {

}
```

3. Listener Container Factory

```
package com.mycompany.factory;

import org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.listener.ContainerProperties;

import com.mycompany.errorhandler.ListenerContainerRecoveringBatchErrorHandler;

public class KafkaBatchListenerContainerFactory<K, V>
        extends ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<K, V> {

    public KafkaBatchListenerContainerFactory(final DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<K, V> consumerFactory,
            final ListenerContainerRecoveringBatchErrorHandler errorHandler, final int concurrency) {

        super.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);
        super.setBatchErrorHandler(errorHandler);
        super.setConcurrency(concurrency);
        super.setBatchListener(true);
        super.setAutoStartup(true);

        final ContainerProperties containerProperties = super.getContainerProperties();
        containerProperties.setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL);
        containerProperties.setOnlyLogRecordMetadata(true);
    }

}
```

4. Batch Error Handler

```
package com.mycompany.errorhandler;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.kafka.listener.RecoveringBatchErrorHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.util.backoff.FixedBackOff;

@Component
public class ListenerContainerRecoveringBatchErrorHandler extends RecoveringBatchErrorHandler {

    public ListenerContainerRecoveringBatchErrorHandler(
            @Value("${spring.kafka.consumer.properties.backOffMS:0}") final int backOffTimeMS,
            @Value("${spring.kafka.consumer.properties.retries:3}") final int retries) {

        super(new FixedBackOff(backOffTimeMS, retries));
    }

}
```

5. Kafka Listener Configurer

```
package com.mycompany.config;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.UUID;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListenerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory;

import com.mycompany.errorhandler.ListenerContainerRecoveringBatchErrorHandler;
import com.mycompany.factory.KafkaBatchListenerContainerFactory;
import com.mycompany.listener.KafkaBatchListener;

@Configuration
public class KafkaBatchListenerConfigurer<K, V> implements KafkaListenerConfigurer {

    private final List<KafkaBatchListener<K, V>> listeners;
    private final BeanFactory beanFactory;
    private final ListenerContainerRecoveringBatchErrorHandler errorHandler;
    private final int concurrency;

    @Autowired
    public KafkaBatchListenerConfigurer(final List<KafkaBatchListener<K, V>> listeners, final BeanFactory beanFactory,
            final ListenerContainerRecoveringBatchErrorHandler errorHandler,
            @Value("${spring.kafka.listener.concurrency:1}") final int concurrency) {
        this.listeners = listeners;
        this.beanFactory = beanFactory;
        this.errorHandler = errorHandler;
        this.concurrency = concurrency;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureKafkaListeners(final KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar registrar) {

        final Method listenerMethod = lookUpBatchListenerMethod();

        listeners.forEach(listener -> {
            registerListenerEndpoint(listener, listenerMethod, registrar);
        });
    }

    private void registerListenerEndpoint(final KafkaBatchListener<K, V> listener, final Method listenerMethod,
            final KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar registrar) {

        // final Map<String, Object> consumerConfig = get ConsumerConfig from a custom provider;
        registrar.setContainerFactory(createContainerFactory(consumerConfig));
        registrar.registerEndpoint(createListenerEndpoint(listener, listenerMethod, consumerConfig));
    }

    private KafkaBatchListenerContainerFactory<K, V> createContainerFactory(final Map<String, Object> consumerConfig) {

        final DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<K, V> consumerFactory = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfig);

        final KafkaBatchListenerContainerFactory<K, V> containerFactory = new KafkaBatchListenerContainerFactory<>(
                consumerFactory, errorHandler, concurrency);

        return containerFactory;
    }

    private MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint<String, String> createListenerEndpoint(final KafkaBatchListener<K, V> listener,
            final Method listenerMethod, final Map<String, Object> consumerConfig) {

        final MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint<String, String> endpoint = new MethodKafkaListenerEndpoint<>();
        endpoint.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        endpoint.setBean(listener);
        endpoint.setMethod(listenerMethod);
        endpoint.setBeanFactory(beanFactory);
        endpoint.setGroupId("my-group-id");
        endpoint.setMessageHandlerMethodFactory(new DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory());

        // final String topicName = get TopicName for this key-value from a custom utility;
        endpoint.setTopics(topicName);

        final Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.putAll(consumerConfig);
        endpoint.setConsumerProperties(properties);

        return endpoint;
    }

    private Method lookUpBatchListenerMethod() {
        return Arrays.stream(com.mycompany.listener.KafkaBatchListener.class.getMethods())
                .filter(m -> m.isAnnotationPresent(com.mycompany.listener.KafkaListener.class))
                .findAny()
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException(
                        String.format("[%s] class should have at least 1 method with [%s] annotation.",
                                com.mycompany.listener.KafkaBatchListener.class.getCanonicalName(),
                                com.mycompany.listener.KafkaListener.class.getCanonicalName())));
    }

}
```

Comment: @GaryRussell Would you mind taking a look at this question? Many thanks!

Comment: Why do you annotate with `@KafkaListener` if your listener already implements `BatchAcknowledgingMessageListener`? `@KafkaListener` is intended for invoking POJO endpoints; if you implement the interface, just pass it into the container directly; please show your listener and configuration so I can understand more what you are trying to do.

Comment: @GaryRussell I need a single listener which uses generics. This way I can avoid duplicate listeners with just different value for topics in Spring's `@KafkaListener` and create listener beans for each key-value pair. These key-value pairs are tied to a single topic and can be processed by their own implementation of a key-value generic service. Question updated with code config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need all the standard `@KafkaListener` method invoking infrastructure when your listener already implements one of the message listener interfaces; instead of registering endpoints for each listener, just create a container for each from the factory and add the listener to the container properties.

```java
val container = containerFactory.createContainer("topic1");
container.getContainerProperties().set...
...
container.getContainerProperies().setMessageListener(myListenerInstance);
...
container.start();
```

Comment: Do you mean to say that I completely remove `KafkaBatchListenerConfigurer.createListenerEndpoint()` and add the suggested code in `KafkaBatchListenerConfigurer.createContainerFactory()`?

Comment: Yes; you don't need all that stuff. It's a lot simpler and much less code.

Comment: Gary - Is it possible to create a my own static thread-pool and share it across all the topics' listeners/containers and still acknowledge at the end of processing? Trying to make sure that the downstream system is not overloaded with large amounts of data as each topic has its own thread-pool which would mean more threads as topics increase.

Comment: No; each container (concurrency) uses a dedicated thread. The framework is not designed to share threads across listeners; it would cause rebalancing if some listener was starved of a thread for more than `max.poll.interval.ms`. You can (somewhat) control throughput by setting the `idleBetweenPolls`. Together with `max.poll.records` you can control the delivery rate of each container. You can also pause/resume containers which will suspend record delivery while keeping the consumer alive.

Comment: Gary - Apologies for continuing the queries in comments... There's a requirement for consuming certain records, say 5 (published one after another to the same topic partition with headers specifying 1of5, 2of5 and so on) in the same batch. This is to ensure they are all persisted in the downstream DB to ensure consistency. If batch 1 consumes just the first 2 messages (due to `max.poll.records` being full), commits the offset and the JVM crashes; incomplete data gets written. Is there a way to avoid this scenario?

Comment: No, there is not - probably the best (only?) way to avoid it by batching the records on the producer side into a single `ProducerRecord`, then de-multiplex it on the consumer side.

Comment: You can use a `RecoveringBatchErrorHandler` throwing a `BatchListenerFailedException` indicating the first record of the incomplete batch. The error handler will commit the offsets of the earlier records and the partial batch will be redelivered on the next poll. This will only work if the max batch size is <= `max.poll.records`.